# How can I override the HTML of options on the user edit page so that they do not appear as collapsible fieldsets?

Tags: theming

In Drupal 7, several modules on the user edit page provide options in collapsible fieldsets (I think this is the right word-- you can click the title above the option and the area containing the option will "collapse" and fold up).

For example,
* timezone (Core)
* whether to receive e-mail notifications upon receipt of messages from other members (privatemsg)
* disable HTML mail (mimemail)

However, I would prefer to have the titles of these options to be regular titles (i.e., even if you click them, they don't collapse; nothing happens).  How can I override this behavior?

I tried the following code based on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8486/how-to-collapse-locale-settings-timezone-in-user-profile-with-hook-form-form):

```
function mymodule_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['timezone']['#collapsible'] = FALSE;
}
```

However, after clearing my cache, the timezone field is still collapsible on the user edit page.

EDIT: I had accidentally called form_user_profile_form_alter twice.  Consolidating the two overrides fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way is to set the [#collapsible](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#collapsible) property to `FALSE`.
As far as I know, when #collapsible is set to `FALSE`, [#collapsed](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#collapsed) is not used anymore, which means the fieldsets are shown as visible; if that is not the case, then set also #collapsed to `FALSE`.

Clearly, this works only for fieldsets; for other form fields, those properties are not used.

As side note, on Drupal 8 collapsible fieldsets are implemented using "details" as form field (at least from the Drupal core code); if you are going to loop through the elements of a form to check for which ones the property should be set, the code should be similar to the following one, for Drupal 8.

```
foreach (element_children($form) as $id) {
  if (!empty($form[$id]) && ($form[$id]['#type'] == 'details' || $form[$id]['#type'] == 'fieldset')) {
    $form[$id]['#collapsible'] = FALSE;
    $form[$id]['#collapsed'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```